# Zero padding - before or after the windowing?

Tags: signal-processing, fft, speech

I am trying to perform the **STFT** on a speech signal. I'd like to know when I should do the zero-padding, before windowing each frame, or after?

My attempt:

```
x    = signal(:);                   % make sure signal is a column vector
sL   = length(x);                   % signal length
wL   = fix(window_Time*fs);         % window length
HOP  = floor(wL*(1 - overlap/100)); % windowing step 
win  = gausswin(wL);                % window type
F    = 1 + fix((sL-wL)/HOP);        % calculate the number of signal     frames
stft = zeros(nfft,F);               % preallocate stft matrix, [nfftxF]

for f = 0:F-1
    xw          = x(1+f*HOP:wL+f*HOP).*win; % windowing
    X           = fftshift(fft([xw;zeros(wL,1)],nfft));   % FFT shifted (double-sided)
    stft(:,1+f) = X;                        % update of the stft matrix
end
```

Comment: Not a programming question - try https://dsp.stackexchange.com ?

Comment: @PaulR I did not know about dsp.stackexchange.com. Thank you for the insight, I'll try there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must do it before the FFT.

1. Divide the signal into frames, see **butter** function;
2. Apply a window to each frames: frames x window;
3. Zero-padd the signal;
4. FFT each windowed frames.

P.S. I've read somewhere that the FFT algorithm already does the zero-padding automatically, i.e., When you to the FFT(x) it will already “padd” the signal x with zeros at the end, to reach the length of the FFT.

Comment: Ok. That makes sense. Thank you @Dirac.

Answer (score -1):

You zero pad frames inside window after windowing to make the window length the power of 2

Comment: Thank you. Something like xframed = [xframed; zeros(windowLength,1)]; And I apply the window to xframed and then the FFT, right? I'm using MATLAB.

Comment: Could you explain a little bit better the part of making the window length the power of 2? Why?

Comment: FFT algorithm requires input to be power of 2, you can check https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/8792/fft-of-size-not-a-power-of-2 for example. Matlab zero-pads automatically, you do not need to pad yourself. See "If X is a vector and the length of X is less than n, then X is padded with trailing zeros to length n" in https://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fft.html

Comment: That makes sense, with or without the zero-padding (done by me), that is no different in the spectrogram. Thanks.

Comment: I did not know that MATLAB does zero-pads automatically, but it makes sense.